# How do I prevent the print function from adding spaces

Tags: python

Im currently writing a program that involves money, and I want my output to have a dollar sign before the output but for some reason python insists on putting a space before my output which will not work for me, so im curious if there is any way around this.

```
amount = int(input("please enter the overall ammount: "))
full_shares = int(input("please enter the number of full shares: "))
print(" ")
half_shares = int(input("please enter the number of halfshares: "))
print(" ")

def split_bill(amount, full_shares, half_shares = 0):
    
    full_share_ammount = amount/full_shares
    half_share_ammount = full_share_ammount/2
    print("Full share: $", full_share_ammount)
    print("Half share: ", half_share_ammount)


split_bill(amount, full_shares, half_shares)
```

output:

```
please enter the overall ammount: 1000
please enter the number of full shares: 4
 
please enter the number of halfshares: 4
 
Full share: $ 250.0
Half share:  125.0
```

Comment: sorry my title didnt really explain my issue, im trying to add a '$' before the output of my program, so for example if my output was 4 I would want it to be $4 if that makes any sense at all.

Answer (score 4):

There are better ways to combine strings, but if you want to use the print function this way, you can provide the `sep` argument with an empty string (it defaults to a single space).

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

```py
>>> print("Full Share $", full_share_amount, sep="")
Full Share $250.0
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively you can use an f-string. This is a way to format variable values in a string:

```
print(f'Full Share ${full_share_amount}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `format` method:

```
print("Full share: ${}".format(full_share_amount))
```

The `{}` is a placeholder. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3101-advanced-string-formatting)